# Python - Selenium - Can't select value from an auto generating drop down menu after a entering value

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Python in order to fill in automaticaly a form.
There is a field where I have to put a value and with this value a drop down menu is generated automaticaly. Based on the value the drop down menu comes with the best suitable answers. Unfortunately I am not able to access the drop down menu regardless of my attempts.

Code:

```
shadow_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sys_display\.sn_vul_vulnerable_item\.cmdb_ci')
shadow_element.send_keys("server_name")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci"]')))
dropdown = Select(element)
element.select_by_visible_text("server_name")
```

Error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on input`

Field code:

```
<input id="sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci" name="sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci" aria-labelledby="label.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="" ac_columns="u_category" ac_order_by="sys_class_name" data-type="ac_reference_input" data-completer="AJAXTableCompleter" data-dependent="" data-dependent-value="" data-ref-qual="" data-ref="sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci" data-ref-key="null" data-ref-dynamic="false" data-name="cmdb_ci" data-table="cmdb_ci" class="form-control element_reference_input" style="; " spellcheck="false" onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXTableCompleter(gel('sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci'), 'sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci', '', ''); e.ac.onFocus();})" aria-required="true" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="AC.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci" title="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Selecting the right value within the drop down menu which is automaticaly generated based on the input value

Thanks a lot

Comment: As the error clearly says, you are trying to use selenium's `Select` class to handle dropdown on a `<input>` element. It should be only used on `<select>` node. Can you share the URL if it is public? If not, at least can you share the HTML in the form of text?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't share the URL as it's a private one. I shared inside my question the portion of the HTML code corresponding of input text field.
Indeed you are right the field is an input and not a select node. But the field is able to generate a drop down menu after typing a value in it.

Comment: I am assuming if you use .send_keys() to the input tag it'll generate the right value correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used to send text into a web element. This uses `Javascript`.

```
my_text = "blahblah"
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('sys_display.sn_vul_vulnerable_item.cmdb_ci').value=' " + my_text + " ' ")
```

**Note:** Ideally you should use Selenium's methods like `send_keys()`, `ActionChains` etc. to send text into a web element. If for any reason selenium can't do it, only then as a last resort you should take help of `JS`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer
Unfortunaly my problem is not that I can't write inside the field it's about selecting the right value in a drop down menu after type the value. I can't access the drop down menu